# Kак правильно выбрать дочерний элемент this?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Подскажите пожалуйста, ка правильно написать следующий код

```js
$('.items').click(function(){
        $('items item').css('display', 'none'); 
    });
```

нужно что бы вместо items было слово this, то есть что бы применялось только к определенному контексту. Пытаюсь делать так, но понимаю что где то ошибка

```js
$('.items').click(function(){
        $('this item').css('display', 'none'); 
    });
```

Comment: Можно еще `$(this).find('.item').css('display', 'none'); `

Comment: большое спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можете использовать функцию find(). И ваше добавление .css('display', 'none') можно заменить функцией hide()

```js
$(document).on('click', '.items', function() {
   $(this).find('.item').hide();
});
```

```css
.items {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background: green;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

.item {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='items'>
   <div class='item'></div>
</div>
<div class='items'>
   <div class='item'></div>
</div>
<div class='items'>
   <div class='item'></div>
</div>
<div class='items'>
   <div class='item'></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.items').click(function(){
        $('.item', this).css('display', 'none'); 
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="items">
  <div class="item">123</div>
  <div class="item">234</div>
</div>
<div class="items">
  <div class="item">aaa</div>
  <div class="item">bbb</div>
</div>
```